# @font-face font stopped working on all but homepage

Tags: css, wordpress, font-face

The font was working across my site but then stopped working on all but the homepage (using Chrome). I checked it out in Firefox and the font isn't working at all. I uploaded the font to my root folder using the Font Squirrel web font generator.

**Font Face**

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'antonioregular';
src: url('antonio-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('antonio-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('antonio-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('antonio-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('antonio-regular-webfont.svg#antonioregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
```

**Heading**

```
h6 {
font-family: 'antonioregular', 'Spinnaker', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.2;
margin: 0 0 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do those URLs actually point to your font? If you are at `http://example.com/foo/bar` it will be looking for the font in your `foo` folder. If the font is in the root, this will fail. Perhaps you meant to include path information in the URL, in your case most likely `src: url('/antonio-regular-webfont.eot');`.

Note: You should be able to use a browser's developer tools to see the requests being made, and the likely 404 returned. This should evoke the "that's not the right location, what is going on?" response.

Answer (score 1):

The file you are loading your fonts on has to be in the same directory, because you do not have any path associated with the font, just the file. Since you say you uploaded it to root, this would explain why only the homepage is getting it.

Provide a relative or absolute path to the files and it should get picked up everywhere.